# Get textarea value from HTML page to Python Flask using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a bit of trouble with figuring out how to get a post from Javascript to work, to my Python Flask server.

Here's the important part of what I've got in my html file

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js </script>
<script type=text/javascript>
    $('a#test').bind('click', function() {
        var textBox = document.getElementById('targetTextArea').value;
        $.post('/postmethod', {text: textBox} );
    });
</script>

<!--textarea-->
<textarea rows="1" cols="20" id="targetTextArea">
</textarea>

<!--button-->
<form method="post" role="form">
<a href=# id=test>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" onClick="writeOut()">
</a>
</form>
```

and here's what I've got in my Python flask file

```
@app.route('/postmethod', methods = ['POST'])
def postmethod():
    data = request.form['text']
    print "Hello world!"
    print data
    return data
```

When I run my python script the textarea and button are there as they should be, but when I type into the textarea and click the button nothing is printed. Please help.

Comment: you also don't need to add `method="post"` to your `<form>` tag because the jQuery code already calls `$.post(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try with the long way? 
Replace `$.post('/postmethod', {text: textBox} );`
for

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "postmethod", //here can be '/postmethod'
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {text: textBox},
        success: function(result) {
            // example
            $('body').html(result)
        }
});
```

This should print on page the content of the variable "data" of python code.

Another thing,

I see that you are using two ways for the submit button, if you use

```
$('a#test').bind('click', function() { //code });
```

then, the  `onClick="writeOut()"` is not neccessary.

I hope you find it useful, regards.

Answer (score 0):

id's value should be in quotes

```
<a href="#" id="test">
        <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" onClick="writeOut()">
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to add

```
$(function() {
});
```

around it

```
$(function() {
    $('a#test').bind('click', function() {
        var textBox = document.getElementById('targetTextArea').value;
        $.post('/postmethod', {text: textBox} );
        return false;
    });
});
```

and also the return false prevents the page of redirecting

sorry guys, I'm new to Javascript. Thank you very much!